# AngularDart: ng-app optional? behavior when ng-app is missing?

Tags: dart, bootstrapping, angular-dart

In the tutorials that I have read so far, they all recommend putting `ng-app` as an attribute to the `<body>` tag, thus identifying that the entire body is part of the template managed by AngularDart. I was surprised to  come across an AngularDart app without an `ng-app` attribute and yet it is still working. How is this?

Comment: And the ng-app attribute is also not on another tag?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [angular library **ngBootstrap**](http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.html#ngBootstrap) Dartdoc says that:

> the root HTML element is used

When no `ng-app` attribute is present. (Fine print: note that `ngBootstrap` `element` and `selector` parameters can affect the choice of root element -- but these parameters have not been used in the elementary examples I have seen so far. In any case, see the Dartdoc for the full details.)